# Camera and GPS location in AndroVM

Tags: android, cordova

I am using androvm for testing of my phonegap application. My application needs to access GPS location and camera. Can anyone tell me how to provide GPS coordinates in androvm like we are providing in emulator provided in eclipse? And how to access my webcam as a camera in androvm?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/).  You can download a version for Windows/Mac OS X/Linux after registering.  A plugin for Eclipse is also avaliable:

> The installation of the plugin can be done by launching Eclipse and going to "Help / Install New Software" menu, then just add a new Update Site with the following URL: http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse. Follow the steps indicated by Eclipse.

GenyMotion allow you to control various sensors of your device including the battery level, signal strength and GPS.

As for the camera I could not find any solutions yet.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem with you, but may be this can be solve yours.

Click [solvedstack.com/questions/running-google-maps-v2-on-the-android-emulator](http://solvedstack.com/questions/running-google-maps-v2-on-the-android-emulator)

I have successfully run our app, which requires Google Maps API 2, on an AndroVM virtual machine.

AndroVM does not come with Google Maps or Google Play installed, but provides a modified copy of the Cyanogen Gapps archive, which is a set of the proprietary Google apps installed on most Android devices.

The instructions, copied from the AndroVM FAQ:

How can I install Google Apps (including the Market/Play app) ?

Download Google Apps : gapps-jb-20121011-androvm.tgz [basically the /system directory from the Cyanogen gapps archive without the GoogleTTS app which crashes on AndroVM]
Untar the gapps…tgz file on your host – you’ll have a system directory created
Get the management IP address of your AndroVM (“AndroVM Configuration” tool) and do “adb connect x.y.z.t”
do “adb root”
reconnect with “adn connect x.y.z.t”
do “adb remount”
do “adb push system/ /system/”
Your VM will reboot and you should have google apps including Market/Play.

You won’t have some Google Apps, like Maps, but they can be downloaded from the Market/Play.
So follow those instructions, then just install Google Maps using Google Play!

Some great side effects of using a VM rather than the emulator:

Vastly superior general performance
OpenGL acceleration
Google Play support
The only bump in the road so far has been lack of multi-touch gestures, which is a bummer for a mapping app! I plan to work around this with a hidden UI mechanism, so not such a huge problem.